# start cron service with supervisor

Tags: 16.04, cron

I have the following in my supervisord.conf:

```
[program:cron]
command=service cron start
autostart=true
autorestart=false
stderr_logfile=/var/log/cron.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/cron.out.log
```

Seems like it's failing?:

```
root@srv:/# supervisorctl
cron                             FATAL     Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
```

However it's running:

```
root@srv:/# ps aux | grep cron
root        52  0.0  0.1  26068  2464 ?        Ss   13:07   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron
root      3053  0.0  0.0  11284   936 ?        S+   13:08   0:00 grep --color=auto cron
```

Am I starting cron correctly with supervisor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Possible to run cron in foreground?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/907395/possible-to-run-cron-in-foreground/907399)

```
command=service cron start
```

Should be instead:

```
command=cron -f
```

Answer (score 1):

With supervisor the program you want to run, needs to stay on the foreground.
You start cron as a service, so the program exits, and supervisor sees it as it stopped.

Comment: Ah makes sense. How do I fix so that cron is in the foreground?