# Possible to run cron in foreground?

Tags: 16.04

I'd like to run the command `/usr/sbin/cron` in the foreground and not as a daemon. Is this possible?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771333/linux-run-cron-job-in-foreground

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`-f` flag is what I was looking for.

`/usr/sbin/cron -f` or `cron -f`